# How to add an assert to an if ..else condition using Phpunit and selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, assert, phpunit

I'm working on test automation for a big project and I'm using `Phpunit` and as a server I'm using `Selenium WebDriver`.

In the source code I'm using asserts like :

```
$this->assertContains('Project Title', $this->webDriver->getTitle());
```

I'm wondering how can I add the if-else condition, that when it's false I can have a popup or to stop the test.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

- For this situation, I have created an array which had only "Project Title"
- When statement gets executed if its has expected title will continue otherwise execution will gets terminated
- Provision has been made to add any condition for title, I just need to add in array

> $this->assertContains($this->webDriver->getTitle(), array('Project
> Title');

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if-else` condition in combination with an `assert` in your PHPUnit test. Here's an example:

```
public function testProjectTitle()
{
    // Get the current title of the web page
    $title = $this->webDriver->getTitle();

    // Check if the title contains 'Project Title'
    if (strpos($title, 'Project Title') === false) {
        // Display a popup or log an error message
        echo 'Project title not found';
    } else {
        // Assert that the title contains 'Project Title'
        $this->assertContains('Project Title', $title);
    }
}
```

In this example, we first get the current title of the web page using `$this->webDriver->getTitle()`. We then use an `if` statement to check if the title contains 'Project Title'. If it does not, we can display a popup or log an error message using `echo`. If the title does contain 'Project Title', we use the `assertContains` method to assert that the title contains the expected string.

Note that if the assertion fails, PHPUnit will automatically stop the test and mark it as failed. If you want to display a popup or log a message in case of a failed assertion, you can do so in the test case's `tearDown` method.